# How to handle Quartz trigger when Computer is turned off during sending push notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

To send push notification daily with the interval of 24 hour, i've use quartz library. But the issue is when my pc is turned off or my network is disconnected, this peace of code is also triggered but my push notification is not send. My question is how can i manage trigger when my pc is turned off or network disconnected? 
I want to send push notification after my pc is turned on or connected to the internet.

```
 ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                  (s =>
                     s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                    .OnEveryDay()
                    .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(11, 00))
                  )
                .Build();

 scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: Also run the method that is triggered with the schedule when your pc is turned on or connected to the internet.

Comment: sorry, do you want see my job method which is triggered after 24 hour?

Comment: No, but you need to trigger that method every time the application starts or internet connectivity is restored.

Comment: Yes, I've already added that part, but issue happened during internet dis connectivity.

Comment: You'll have to build a new method that checks the connectivity and set a new interval job to check that every x seconds.

Comment: @sakibrahman Did you send your push notifications from your pc?

Comment: yes, I'd send push notification from my pc(server) using FCM @Rabban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of [Misfire Instructions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html), a [JobExecutionException](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/e155e960-3c46-0d5e-03fa-943f60544743.htm) and the [DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html)

1. Set the `DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute` on your Job, this will prevent you from executing multiple instances of the same jobs at the same time.

   ```
   [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
   public class MyJob : IJob
   {
   ....
   }
   ```
2. Set the `Misfire Instruction` to your Trigger, this will tell your trigger to fire immediately in case it missed an execution.

   ```
   ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
           .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
             (s =>
                s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
               .OnEveryDay()
               .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(11, 00))
               .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()
             )
           .Build();
   ```
3. Catch any exception during the execution of your job e.g. when the internet is not reachable and throw a `JobExecutionException` telling Quartz that the trigger should be fired again.

   ```
   public class MyJob : IJob
   {
       public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
       {
           try
           {
               // connect to internet or whatever.....
           }
           catch(Exception)
           {
               throw new JobExecutionException(true);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Next time, read the [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/index.html) first ;)